# Multiple Regression - Extreme F-statistic and R-square on 1 - too good to be true?

Tags: regression, r-squared, f-statistic

I have used a psychometric survey of 10 items which measure risk perception. 
I have taken the mean scores of these 10 items from a sample of 355 respondents who rated six hazards via the 10 Psychometric questions. I have performed a multiple regression where my criterion variable is a weighted composite scale from an estimation of risk consequence survey. My results are as follows - 
"In combination, the neutral Psychometric Dread risk factor accounted for a significant 100% of variability in neutral estimations of the severity of risk consequence, R2  = 1.0, adjusted R2  = 1.0, F (10, 355) = 18521487.85, p = .001"
I have never seen an F-statistic this high, and the r-square = 1.
My question is - Is this result possible, and if so, how likely it it?

Thank you!

Mel

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more regarding what your variables are? How many independent variables are there? The use of 10 items, six hazards, and a composite scale confuses the matter.